# How to store socket object in session expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

```
io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    req.session.socket = socket;    
});
```

I want to store the socket object in session of an user. But not able to because the req object in the callback is not persisting the change. It's not available the next time I try to access it. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
   yourSessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    socket.request.session.socket = socket;    
});
```

yourSessionMiddleware looks like:

```
var yourSessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: "super secret word"
});
```

Comment: The session object is missing on the request object.

Comment: @AnilDukkipatty my mistake, changed the answer.

Comment: When I include the midleware function you've mentioned the socket object events are not firing 'io.on(...)'

Comment: @AnilDukkipatty Session middleware mounted with app.use(yourSessionMiddleware) string?

Comment: I am using `var session = require('express-session');`

`app.use(session({
 secret: 'somesecret',
 store: sessionstore.createSessionStore()
}));`
`io.use(function(socket, next) {
 session(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});`

Comment: @AnilDukkipatty You need to store session in a new variable like it shown in my answer.